# Apache Server error 500 when DocumentRoot is a symlink

Tags: php, apache, fedora, symlink, selinux

I have setup my fedora system, the default was that `/` size is 50gb while remaining drives where put on `/home`.

since I don't want to waste my precious 50gb for my web project I setup my apache web server as follow

since the default of apache is `/var/www/html`

i remove `html` dir and replace it with a symbolic link that points to my `/home/user/www/html`

note `/home`, `/home/user`, `/home/user/www`, `/home/user/www/html` have `x` permission for apache

my conf is like this

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None 
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I already restart my httpd service and it was fine. The problem is when I try to access my index.php I get a server error. when it's index.html I get a 403.

my selinux is currently enabled and no plans on disabling it. I would Like to learn how to use it rather. so it this an selinux problem?

As I run ls -Zla on `/home/user/www/html`, this is the result

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0   27 Dec 21 22:37 index.php
```

It seems that SELinux is preventing this

when accessing an html

```
[Mon Dec 21 23:35:33.749916 2015] [core:error] [pid 20579] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:45632] AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/html/index.html
```

when a php

```
    [Mon Dec 21 23:39:36.801672 2015] [:error] [pid 20585] [client 127.0.0.1:45816] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Dec 21 23:39:36.801730 2015] [:error] [pid 20585] [client 127.0.0.1:45816] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

~

Comment: read your apache error log for the reason

Comment: Just a note — rather than making a symlink, you could simply change the DocumentRoot to whereever you like. (You'll still need the right selinux labels, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

to someone that may get this problem. change the selinux type of the folder using this command.

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/user/www
```

more [info](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html)